# BigQuery logs disappearing (2016/12/16)

Tags: google-bigquery

Since this morning, I have many issues with Google BigQuery service.

My logs seems to disappear after few minutes. It's reproductible.

Here you can see a sample test with the issue.

1) [Query my table at T-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbBST.jpg)

```
SELECT * FROM  [mytable]
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

2) [After, a new log insertion, the previous one is deleted and the new one is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riY2Z.jpg)

3) After few more seconds, the new log is visible

This loop from 1 to 3 is infinite. If I insert a new log, the case 2) then 3) will happened.

I use BigQuery for more than 2 years, it's the first time this issue happened on my account.

Have you any idea on what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: how you do insertion. are you streaming or loading or DMLing, etc.

Comment: Stream with insertAll method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using insertAll - check [insertId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll#rows.insertId) property.
My guess is  - it possible that you have it the same for your respective inserts  - thus they treatred as duplicates and being removed/deleted and latest survives

Comment: Perfect, this is working :) I have removed the insertId auto-generation of my script and logs are not disappearing now. Thank you !